# Script to kill started application

Tags: powershell

I am looking to:

- delete the contents of a folder
- run an application

  - then put in a Kill command (`Stop-Process`) if it runs longer than a specified period of time.

But I'm not sure where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Task Scheduler.

Comment: You're on the right track with `Stop-Process`.  There are other cmdlets like `Test-Path`, `Remove-Item`, `Start-Process`, and `Get-Process`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are starting the application from a PowerShell script, *and waiting in that script...* then you just need a way to keep track of time in your script before calling `Stop-Process`. You'll also need to be sure you know what process you are going to kill.

A simple implementation could use `Start-Sleep` in a loop:

```
$pid = PID OF THE RUNNING APPLICATION
$iter = 0
while((Get-Process -Id $pid)){
    $iter++
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    if($iter -gt 60) {
        Stop-Process -Id $pid
        break
    }
 }
```

If your process was started elsewhere you might need to pull the process start time. This doesn't seem to be returned by `Get-Process` so you might want to try a WMI query:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'APP.exe'"-Property Name,CreationDate
```

You can then look for instances of APP.exe that started before a certain time.

Comment: `StartTime` is returned by `Get-Process` -- `(Get-Process firefox).StartTime`

Comment: Not reliably in my experience, although it might depend on whether you have local admin rights, based on a little testing just now.

Answer (score -1):

Before you try to delete an item (folder/file) check it exists:

```
$folder = "C:\folder"
if (Test-Path $folder) { Remove-Item $folder -Recurse }
```

Stop process if it's been running for 30mins:

```
Get-Process firefox | Where StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) | Stop-Process -Force
```